# Converting to a specific date format?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, format

I am making a webpage in Asp.net MVC. I need to format a datetime into the correct format.

How can I convert a datetime to this format shown in SQL:

**2015-10-23 14:57:43.083** (example)

Thanks!

Comment: Just use a format string - e.g. `yourDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss");` if you want a specific display format in your view

Comment: @EilHellmer you could have easily done a Google search in the meantime here is a really good site that has lots of good [C# Examples](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) you will find plenty of information on how to format dates. On the first look I think you'll need something like this:

```
myDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss")
```